# How do I find out who created a Google Form

Tags: google-drive, google-forms, google-drive-sharing

I opened a Google Form and can't find it on any of my Google accounts - perhaps a colleague created it.

Students have responded, but I can't find the original to see the responses.

Is there any way of finding out who created the form in the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to **My Drive** (any Google page, the 9 square/hashtag symbol, 'Drive'), and then go to **Shared with me** you can find a list of every Google Document that has been shared with you. The second column in the list shows who shared each item with you. Possibly, the sharer is NOT the owner (someone with edit rights can also have the ability to share a document), but that can at least give you a hint of who else to ask to follow up.

[image: Screenshot of Google Hashtag button]

[image: Google Drive Button]

[image: Shared with Me showing 'Shared By' column]

The other possible problem is that the form for gathering responses and the Spreadsheet for collecting them are two separate documents, so it's entirely possible you currently only have access to the form, but NOT the Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this situation as a Google Workspace admin and this response is geared towards Google Workspace admins who are trying to track down a form owner.

---

The Document ID in the form link would be here → https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/(Document ID)/viewform

You should usually be able to take the ID from the url and find it in https://admin.google.com > Reporting > Audit and investigation > Drive log events and search using the Document ID. In my case the form I was asked to find the owner for was *not* returning results here.

The next thing you can do is submit a dummy response on the form then go to https://admin.google.com > Reporting > Email Log Search and search for "Response" with results for only Today.

It'll take a minute or two for it to appear in the logs but there will be an email titled "*"[Your Form Name] (Responses)" was edited recently*" at the bottom of the results. The recipient shown here will be the person you want to contact.

---

Adding this response because if I just accepted Google Support's response I would've thought there was no way to find or access the original form. It turned out to be on a Shared Drive I had access to so I didn't need to request access to the form itself or anything.

From there it was straight forward to add others as collaborators to the form once I opened it up.